# find other columns value based on maximum of one column using groupby particular column

Tags: sql, hive

I have data like below

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Count |  Mindif | Device |
+-------+---------+--------+
|    45 |       3 |    A   |
|    78 |       4 |    A   |
|    52 |       5 |    A   |
|    24 |       6 |    A   |
|    22 |       1 |    B   |
|    22 |       2 |    B   |
|    34 |       3 |    B   |
|    37 |       4 |    B   |
|    52 |       5 |    B   |
|    34 |       6 |    B   |
|    13 |       1 |    C   |
|    30 |       2 |    C   |
|    57 |       3 |    C   |
|   111 |       4 |    C   |
|    35 |       5 |    C   |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

Want to find Mindif and device based on max value of count.
Output be like

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| Count |  Mindif | Device |
+-------+---------+--------+
|    78 |       4 |    A   |
|    52 |       5 |    B   |
|   111 |       4 |    C   |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.Count, t1.Mindif, t1.Device
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT Device, MAX(Count) AS Count
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY Device
) AS t2 ON t1.Device = t2.Device AND t1.Count = t2.Count
```

The query uses a derived table that returns the max `Count` value per `Device`. Joining back to the original table we can get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**using Window Function**

```
SELECT Count, Mindif, Device
FROM
 (SELECT Count, Mindif, Device,
         rank() over (order by Count desc) as r 
  FROM table) S 
WHERE S.r = 1;
```

OR

**Simple Join with MAX**

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a 
LEFT SEMI JOIN  
(SELECT MAX(Count)Cnt 
 FROM table)b on (a.Count  = b.Cnt)
```